# White space below the footer

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, footer

In the home page of my site there is a big white space after the footer.

You can check here

Comment: Your 4th menu has lots of submenus which creates this issue. If you remove the 4th menu then it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is cause by the submenu for `Merceria`. It's waaaaay too big.
Removing that submenu makes the empty space go away.
You may consider displaying your submenus on multiple columns.

Comment: You know how to display it on multiple columns?

Comment: Depends on your theme. There is no one size fits all solution